# Search inside 70gb of PDF files

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have 70gb PDF files, and I want to search inside them with PHP and some Ajax.

The code must search on all PDF files and extract the data out into table,
For example: 1547AD

When I hit enter the code will search in all PDF files and extract all PDF files that contain "1547AD" inside them.

My problem is: of course putting these data inside MySQL will be better for the server and stronger but imagine extracting all tables in 70GB of PDF files! and these pdf files updated daily, also there is alot of traffic on this page.

**My question is: Is it the right way to build this in PHP or I should use another language and/or another method for this kind of heavy data?**

Comment: What are these PDF files? What data do they have?

Comment: electronics datasheets

Comment: ok, what kind of data will be searched?

Comment: One possibility would be to convert the PDF files (one time and as added) into text files then use something like Elastic Search to store and search the documents (with a link back to the original PDF file). Fast, flexible and reasonable.

Comment: @vivek_23 numbers and sometimes letters

Comment: @mlewis54 it's a good idea, but I will lose alot of function when I convert the file to txt, I can't extract the tables inside them correclty..

Comment: @jason5137715 70 GB is a lot. You will need some parallel processing for faster response. Also, how are you going to display this to the user? Are you going to list all PDF files that had the searched value?

Comment: @jason5137715 You shouldn't lose any information. You are only converting the PDFs to text to load into Elastic Search. This is done so people can search on the contents of the PDF quickly (should be sub-one second in elastic search). You would then display the original PDF from a table you generate from the results returned by elastic search..

Comment: @vivek_23 yes only the name of the pdf file, mlewis54 I will give it a try

Comment: Also using Elasticsearch like @mlewis54 suggests will allow you to build relevant indexes over the documents to speed searches, and facilitate scaling your search infrastructure out. If you were to just write a PHP function to iterate over 70GB of PDFs for every single search you would likely be waiting literal HOURS for any given search.

Comment: I've used PHP + MySQL to index ~2TB of PDF, no problem. Once you catch up with the backlog, and you stay on top of it, it's not a big deal. (Provided your search index schema is aligned with your queries and goes to lengths to minimize performance hits.)